# How to by pass SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE in GeckoFX 29?

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I am implementing a GeckoFX Browser using c# in winform application. I want to by pass `SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE` error (`Certificate key usage inadequate for attempted operation.`).

I have tried the below code. but its not working.

```
    browser.NSSError += (s,e) => {
    CertOverrideService.RememberRecentBadCert(e.Uri);
    Uri refUrl = browser.Url;
    this.Navigate(args.Uri.AbsoluteUri, GeckoLoadFlags.FirstLoad, refUrl != null ? refUrl.AbsoluteUri : null,null);
    e.Handled = true;
};
```